# jQuery scrollable tabs inside accordian control

Tags: jquery

We have been using the code found here to make scrollable tabs http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/dECtZ/ and it seems to be working OK but recently we put this inside an accordion control and we are now having problems.

If you look here: http://jsfiddle.net/dECtZ/188/ I have modified to have it inside an accordion control and the problem we have is if you swap tabs and swap sections on the accordion a few times the scrollable arrow on the right starts appearing even if there are not enough items to warrant scrolling.

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am at a loss on how to fix this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Removing the following code worked for me:

```
        $(window).bind("resize.tabs", function(e) {
                var navWidth = 0;
                var arrowWidth = navPrev.outerWidth();
                nav.find("li").each(function() {
                    navWidth += $(this).outerWidth(true);
                });

                var marginLeft = -(parseInt(nav.css("marginLeft"), 10)),
                    hwidth = self.header.width();

                if (navWidth > (hwidth+marginLeft)) {
                    self.header.addClass("ui-tabs-arrow-r");
                    navNext.show("fade");
                    if (marginLeft > 0) {
                        self.header.addClass("ui-tabs-arrow-l");
                        navPrev.show("fade");
                    } else {
                        self.header.removeClass("ui-tabs-arrow-l");
                        navPrev.hide("fade");
                    }
                } else {
                    self.header.removeClass("ui-tabs-arrows ui-tabs-arrow-l");
                    navNext.hide("fade");
                    if (marginLeft > 0) {
                        self.header.addClass("ui-tabs-arrow-l");
                        navPrev.show("fade");
                    } else {
                        self.header.removeClass("ui-tabs-arrow-l");
                        navPrev.hide("fade");
                    }
                }
            }).trigger("resize.tabs");
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, we want the scrollable function to work when there are more tabs as they are dynamically added but in this scenario there aren't enough tabs to need the scrolling but the arrow is still appearing but only when it is inside the Accordion.  Thanks for taking the time to post but I hop that makes more sense now.